# How do I select text from the cursor position to the begining of a paragraph with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, textselection

I am formatting a specific type of name in a large document. The correct format is "*Name of term (REC)* [Date]" where the entire phrase is italicized with the exception of the date. I am currently using the following code:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "(REC)"
            .Replacement.Text = "*"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.Font.Italic = wdToggle
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
        Loop
```

This works fine unless the italicized phrase breaks over two lines. I get something like the following: 
"Name of Term Term Term Term Term Term
*Term Term Term (REC)* [Date]"
where the first line does not get italicized. Does VBA have a way of selecting only at the cursor position to the beginning of the current paragraph?
Please feel free to suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selects all from the insertion point to the beginning of the paragraph. This will not work at the very beginning of a document, since there is no preceding return:

```
Selection.MoveStartUntil Cset:=vbCr, Count:=wdBackward
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. There are various ways to go about it, but a fairly straight-forward one is to use the `MoveStart` method of the `Range` or `Selection` object.

Personally, I prefer working with a `Range` rather than `Selection` as it's more flexible, faster and there's less "screen flicker". But the approach shown below works for both, just the same.

```
Dim rngFind As Range

Set rngFind = ActiveDocument.Content 'search the document body

rngFind.Find.ClearFormatting
rngFind.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With rngFind.Find
        .Text = "(REC)"
        .Replacement.Text = "*"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Do While rngFind.Find.Execute = True
        rngFind.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        rngFind.MoveStart Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=-1
        rngFind.Font.Italic = wdToggle
        rngFind.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
```

Comment: This works, however, my library doesn't recognize 
rngFind.MoveRight
I changed the line to 
rngFind.Move Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1 and it works perfectly. Also it runs twice as fast as my original code.
Today, you have taught a man to fish!

Comment: Glad you enjoy fishing... Ah, I see my error: it should be `MoveEnd` (rather than `MoveRight`). Also, you should mark the contribution that *best* answers your quesiton as "the" answer. You are allowed to change it... Later, when you have 15 rep points on the site, you'll also be able to *upvote* all contribuations (questions as well as answers) that you find to be helpful. These actions help others and maintain the site quality :-) Enjoy, @Thribben!